# Vertex handles in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, polygon, fabricjs, bezier

Does FabricJS have vertex handles builtin? I mean the possibility to move position of polygon points and bezier control points using handles

Comment: Nothing like this built-in, but this is really a higher-level functionality. You can build it atop of Fabric easily. See http://fabricjs.com/polygon-animation/ and http://fabricjs.com/interaction-with-objects-outside-canvas/

Comment: It would be fine to be built-in. There would be then different level of selections: group selection, object selection and vertex selection. I think this is as high-level functionality as group and object selection.

Comment: Group selection and object selection is really the same thing; but yes, you're probably right about it being on the same level as selection. Just like in Illustrator, 2 different modes — vertex modification and object selection.